# How to validate a date from datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api, datetimepicker

I want to use JQuery to validate a date selected from a datetimepicker. What I want is not only disable weekends by applying `daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6]`, but also guarantee the selected date be 2 days later than the current date. For example, if today is Monday, then I can only select a date from Tuesday this week; if today is Friday, then next Monday is the earliest one can be selected. The following is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(
        $(
            function () {
                $('#date').datetimepicker({
                    //viewMode: 'years',
                    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A',
                    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
                    //inline: true,
                    sideBySide: true,
                });
            }
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate

```
$(document).ready(
    $(
        function () {
            $('#date').datetimepicker({
                minDate: '+2d',
                //viewMode: 'years',
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A',
                daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
                //inline: true,
                sideBySide: true,
            });
        }
    )
)
```